# How to update stream_socket_client ssl version 3

Tags: ssl, stream-socket-client

I can see we can change ssl version to ssl3 in curl but how to do this in "stream_socket_client"

```
   <?php
function getSSLPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

var_dump(getSSLPage("https://google.com"));
?>
```